# cannot open source file "node.h" in hello.cc

Tags: node.js

- **Node Version**:v12.1.0
- **Platform**:Mac osx
- **node-gyp**:v5.0.3

I don't know if it's a problem or just a personal question 。as a nodejs addons beginner,I write a 
hello.cc file,which as below:

```cpp
    #include <node.h>
    #include <v8.h>
    using namespace v8;
    // 实现定义的方法
    Handle<Value> SayHello(const Arguments &args)
    {
        HandleScope scope;
        return scope.Close(String::New("Hello world!"));
    }
    // 给传入的目对象加sayHello()方法 void Init_Hello(Handle<Object>target) {

    target->Set(String::NewSymbol("sayHello"),FunctionTemplate::New(SayHello)->GetFunction());
// 调用NODE_MODULE()方法将注方法定义内存中 NODE_MODULE(hello, Init_Hello)
```

and my binding.gyp is like this:

```js
    {
        'targets': [
            {
                'target_name': 'hello', 'sources': [
                    'src/hello.cc'],
                'conditions': [['OS == "mac"',
                                {
                                }
                                ]],
                "include_dirs": [
                    "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
                ]
            }]
    }
```

but the source code show Squiggles
[image: issue]

and when I run `node-gyp configure build`

error shows:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question adding your binding.gyp

Comment: done, the code format is more strict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all right version problem.

use nan.h fixed

https://github.com/nodejs/nan